# Read information of a filme mp3

Tags: java, mp3

I'm trying to create a program that reads the information on mp3 files (album, artist, etc.) in a particular folder.
Searching the internet I found the library [Java ID3 Tag Library](http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/index.html).

I wrote this simple class:

```
package main;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.farng.mp3.MP3File;
import org.farng.mp3.TagException;
import org.farng.mp3.id3.ID3v1;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TagException {

    File sourceFile = new File("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\Adele\\Tired.mp3");
    MP3File mp3file = new MP3File(sourceFile);
    ID3v1 tag = mp3file.getID3v1Tag();
    System.out.println(tag.getAlbum());
    System.out.println(tag.getAlbumTitle());
    System.out.println(tag.getTitle());

  }

}
```

When I run, eclipse generates this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.farng.mp3.id3.FrameBodyRVAD.setupObjectList(Unknown Source)
    at org.farng.mp3.AbstractMP3FragmentBody.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.farng.mp3.id3.AbstractID3v2FrameBody.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.farng.mp3.id3.FrameBodyRVAD.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.farng.mp3.id3.AbstractID3v2Frame.readBody(Unknown Source)
    at org.farng.mp3.id3.ID3v2_3Frame.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.farng.mp3.id3.ID3v2_3Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.farng.mp3.id3.ID3v2_3.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.farng.mp3.id3.ID3v2_3.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.farng.mp3.MP3File.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.farng.mp3.MP3File.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

How can I fix?
Thanks!

PS: I added the jar file in the library.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that your test mp3 file doesn't have an ID3v1 tag? Use `if(mp3file.hasID3v1Tag())` to see if that tag even exists. If it doesn't exist, that would be a good reason why you can't get it from your mp3.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Thanks for the reply. I added control but the problem isn't this...

Comment: Please include your updated code. Also, make sure that line 16 which the stack trace points to as the source of the problem is indeed `ID3v1 tag = mp3file.getID3v1Tag;` Remember that we can't see the line numbers in your IDE if you don't post them.